# ffmpeg Get Audio Samples in a specific AVSampleFormat from AVFrame

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am looking at the example from ffmpeg docs:
[Here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decode_audio_8c-example.html)

```
static int output_audio_frame(AVFrame *frame)
{
    size_t unpadded_linesize = frame->nb_samples * av_get_bytes_per_sample(frame->format);
    printf("audio_frame n:%d nb_samples:%d pts:%s\n",
           audio_frame_count++, frame->nb_samples,
           av_ts2timestr(frame->pts, &audio_dec_ctx->time_base));
    /* Write the raw audio data samples of the first plane. This works
     * fine for packed formats (e.g. AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16). However,
     * most audio decoders output planar audio, which uses a separate
     * plane of audio samples for each channel (e.g. AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P).
     * In other words, this code will write only the first audio channel
     * in these cases.
     * You should use libswresample or libavfilter to convert the frame
     * to packed data. */
    fwrite(frame->extended_data[0], 1, unpadded_linesize, audio_dst_file);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is decoder's format cant be set so it will give me audio samples in any of the following types:

```
enum AVSampleFormat {
      AV_SAMPLE_FMT_NONE = -1, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S32,
      AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8P, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P,
      AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S32P, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBLP, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S64,
      AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S64P, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_NB
    }
```

I am working with a sound engine and the engine requres me to send float [-1 to 1] PCM data to the engine so I would like to obtain the frame's audio data as float for the two channels (stereo music). How may I do that? Do I need to use libswresample? If so can anyone sent me an example for my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Encoding audio Example](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encode_audio_8c-example.html)
- [Resampling audio Example](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/resampling_audio_8c-example.html)
- [Transcoding Example](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/transcoding_8c-example.html)

If you don't get the desired format from the decoder, you have to resample it, encode with AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT.

According to [enum AVSampleFormat](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/group__lavu__sampfmts.html#gaf9a51ca15301871723577c730b5865c5)

- The floating-point formats are based on full volume being in the range [-1.0, 1.0]. Any values outside this range are beyond full volume level.

All the Examples are well documented and not that complicated. The function names alone are very explanatory, so it shouldn't be that hard to understand.

Comment: I do not agree with `All the Examples are well documented and not that complicated.` but since i do not have any other sources i will dig into these examples more

Comment: Ok, agreed, maybe not all, but i have seen worse. The last time i worked with the av libs, was a decade ago, but i remember to used the examples from them, there was not more available. The sources of mplayer is a good source for learning too.

Comment: I agree, the library itself is amazing but oh man, there is no good resources available to tell you how it works and how to use it properly. I even checked udemy but nope, nothing.

Comment: What is making you the most headache? Maybe i could say something to that.

Comment: Its just the overall library itself. I want to know how things work internally, how to decode audio with zero margin on errors and stuff but it takes lots of time, for example, I spent 2 days trying to understand demuxing_decoding.c example. Its just complicated, some thing are not explained very well

Comment: Well, how things work internally, good luck with that. But basically you have format (container), codec_context (wrapper for the codec), codec (en-/decoder) and packet (data container). One of the problems i remember, since you use av_format for source and sink, it is hard to tell which of the fields of the format structure is set when and for what. codec context the same. Therefore the simpliest thing to do is to rely on the interface of the api and not to mess with the internals. To understand the interface, reading the docs and studying the examples and of course, to experiment.

Comment: can you check my latest question also